# Installing and using MPlib

Tags: metapost

I have been able to find the manual for MPlib on CTAN, but where can I find the C sources for the library itself? Sorry for asking such a basic question.

Comment: http://www.tug.org/metapost.html

Comment: I cannot find sources for MPlib off any link there - not even the header file. Probably my fault, but I can't.

Comment: `svn checkout http://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/metapost trunk`

Comment: Marco, would you like to make that an answer and then I can accept it? I realise now I have to actually build the software for the headers etc to appear

Comment: @Marco Would you like to turn your comment into an answer? (Adrian: users aren't notified about comments to posts that are not their own, unless you write `@username`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project is hosted on [FusionForge](https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/metapost/). You can obtain the source code with Subversion using:

```
svn checkout https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/metapost trunk
```

Note the **https**! The old URL from my comment above is not valid any longer since FusionForge restructured their site.