# Where is source code of TeX, LuaTeX, pdfTeX

Tags: tex-core

Today, TeX is a big program, LuaTeX, PDFTeX, METAPOST etc.
Where is the public accessing source code for hacking LuaTeX or other implementations. For example, I need to embed TeX into C program or creating Ruby object TeX.

Comment: The source code for LaTeX and TeX is written in TeX.  The original engine was written in Pascal and translated into various other languages (there is a test for validation).  You might have better luck running LaTeX as a separate server with a custom driver.

Comment: Note that TeX90, pdfTeX, XeTeX, _etc._ are written in WEB (a form of specialised Pascal source), and are nowadays built using WEB2C (part of TeX Live); LuaTeX is natively in C.

Comment: Pls confirm if Duplicate of [How to compile the source code of TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111332/how-to-compile-the-source-code-of-tex), [XeTeX source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65499/xetex-source-code) and [Installing and using MPlib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93806/15717)

Comment: While not exactly answering the question, there is also [C/WEB programs in TeX Live 2023](https://tug.ctan.org/info/knuth-hint/) (also found in https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/info/knuth-hint/) which contains the *typesetted* changes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## TeX Live:

- WWW: https://www.tug.org/texlive/
- SVN: svn://tug.org/texlive/
- SVN web interface (ViewVC): https://tug.org/svn/texlive/
- Mirror: https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source

## XeTeX:

- WWW: https://xetex.sourceforge.net/
- Git: https://git.code.sf.net/p/xetex/code
- Git web interface: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code

## LuaTeX

- WWW: http://www.luatex.org
- Main Git repo: https://gitlab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/texlive/luatex
- Git mirror: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex

## MetaPost

- WWW: https://www.tug.org/metapost.html
- SVN: https://serveur-svn.lri.fr/svn/modhel/metapost (`anonsvn` / `anonsvn`)

## pdfTeX

- WWW: https://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/
- SVN: svn://tug.org/pdftex
- SVN web interface (ViewVC): https://tug.org/svn/pdftex/

Comment: The LuaTeX repository just screams "we don't want any contributions"

Answer (score 11):

The complete sources from which TeX Live is built are available to browse online on a GitHub mirror (note that this is not the upstream source which is a private SVN).

https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source

Therein you can find the source for the different components:

- TeX: [`texk/web2c/tex.web`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/web2c/tex.web)
- pdfTeX: [`texk/web2c/pdftexdir`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/trunk/texk/web2c/pdftexdir)
- LuaTeX: [`texk/web2c/luatexdir`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/trunk/texk/web2c/luatexdir)
- XeTeX: [`texk/web2c/xetexdir`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/trunk/texk/web2c/xetexdir)

The experimental LuaTeX also has its own [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex).  There you can find the source in the directory [`source/texk/web2c/luatexdir`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/tree/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir).

Comment: broken links for the sub links.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy The branch has been renamed from `master` to `trunk`.  I fixed the links.

Comment: Either not, or no longer a private SVN, I reckon: https://tug.org/svn/texlive/

Answer (score 9):

TeX

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex

This is a good starting point.

LuaTeX

http://www.luatex.org/download.html

Comment: Luatex link not workin. SVN repository have password. This is wrong answer

Comment: @MarkoLustro I don't follow how it's wrong: that _is_ the official master repo for LuaTeX. One could get the TeX Live version (https://www.tug.org/texlive/svn/), which if you are happy with 'reasonable approximation to current release' is OK, but it's not the 'master' source.

Comment: Yes this is oficial web but I cant download source code from this web

Comment: A quick google search will tell you user name and passwort

Comment: @MarkoLustro You are expected to ask for it I think

Comment: Username:anonsvn    Password:anonsvn

Comment: A "quick" search does not immediately reveal the username and password. (Thanks, Neelix.) However, is it not the case that luatex is distributed under an open license that requires the source code to be publicly available? Why should there be a username and password, even if known?

Comment: It is not that uncommon to require a publicly available username and password for a free repo. However, if 'ask for it' in @JosephWright 's sense means 'email somebody or fill in a form or ....' then that might be problematic for some free licences. But unless they're releasing binaries of the master, it is unlikely to violate anything, so long as source of the releases is easily available. Few (no?) licences say you have to release code for stuff you don't distribute.