# Reading LuaTeX source

Tags: luatex, sourcecode

TL;DR: I want to read the source code of LuaTeX. How and where?

I want to know exactly how the Knuth-Plass algorithm for line breaking is implemented in LuaTeX. Not an explanation, I want the source. The Lua callback for the algorithm is `tex.linebreak`. I downloaded the "source" from https://serveur-svn.lri.fr/svn/modhel/luatex and searched for `linebreak` throughout all files; it only occurs in a data structure declaration. Even more annoying, I couldn't even find *where* is the source for the LuaTeX engine. I am of course assumming LuaTeX is open source, but after two days looking for it, go figure `:)`

Comment: Special case of [tex core - Where is source code of TeX, LuaTeX, pdfTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385380/where-is-source-code-of-tex-luatex-pdftex)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The master luatex svn sources are currently not at a publicly accessible location, I understand that this is an essentially temporary situation due to a change of hosting arrangements however the luatex developers push regularly to the texlive svn so that is usually only days or at most weeks behind. Texlive svn is browsable at https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/

specifically

https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/linebreak.w?view=markup&sortby=date

starts with the comment

> @ We come now to what is probably the most interesting algorithm of \TeX: the mechanism for choosing the ``best possible'' breakpoints
>   that yield the individual lines of a paragraph. \TeX's line-breaking
>   algorithm takes a given horizontal list and converts it to a sequence
>   of boxes that are appended to the current vertical list. In the course
>   of doing this, it creates a special data structure containing three
>   kinds of records that are not used elsewhere in \TeX. Such nodes are
>   created while a paragraph is being processed, and they are destroyed
>   afterwards; thus, the other parts of \TeX\ do not need to know
>   anything about how line-breaking is done.

D Knuth's text, from the original tex.web sources.

Comment: Actually the address you give in the question is the upstream master source but it's currently password protected  and I didn't feel at liberty to announce the address or certainly not the password.

Comment: I do know the password. I don't know why it is protected, but I hope not to have made anything inappropriate. Anyway, thank you so much, this will really help.

Comment: The password is practically public—I remember encountering it when I was looking for the LuaTeX sources a while ago, and one of the “official” pages (IIRC) mentioned the password. It was so easy to find that I didn't even bother remembering the password, sure that I would find it again if needed. :-)

Comment: There is also a non official mirror of LuaTeX @ github: https://github.com/speedata/LuaTeX

Comment: There is now an official LuaTeX mirror: https://github.com/tex-live/luatex

Comment: For anyone else who is looking for the respective file on Github, here is the link: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/linebreak.c